# discord.js-menu - allowing everyone to react/control page

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Link/Guide that I'm using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-menu

My code is:

```js
/* Import all the usual stuff. This shouldn't be anything new. */
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const { Menu } = require('discord.js-menu')
const client = new Client()

/* Run this code every time a new message is sent. */
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === "!help") {
        /*
         * The menu class takes 4 parameters. 
         * 1) A channel to send the menu to
         * 2) A user ID to give control over the navigation, 
         * 3) An array of Page objects, each being a unique page of the menu
         * 4) How long, in milliseconds, you want the menu to wait for new reactions
         */
        let helpMenu = new Menu(message.channel, message.author.id, [
            {
                /*
                 * A page object consists of three items:
                 * 1) A name. This is used as a unique destination name for reactions.
                 * 2) Some content. This is a rich embed. 
                 * You can use {object: formatting} or .functionFormatting() for embeds. Whichever you prefer.
                 * 3) A set of reactions, linked to either a page destination or a function.* (See example pages)
                 * 
                 * Reactions can be emojis or custom emote IDs, and reaction destinations can be either the names
                 * of pages, () => { functions }, or special destination names. See below for a list of these.
                 */

                /* You can call pages whatever you like. The first in the array is always loaded first. */
                name: 'p1',
                content: new MessageEmbed({
                    title: 'Page 1',
                    description: 'This is some helpful info!',
                    fields: [
                        { name: "this is page 1", value: "p1" }
                    ]
                }),
                reactions: {
                    '❌': 'p1',
                    '➡': 'p2'
                }
            },
            {
                /*
                 * A page object consists of three items:
                 * 1) A name. This is used as a unique destination name for reactions.
                 * 2) Some content. This is a rich embed. 
                 * You can use {object: formatting} or .functionFormatting() for embeds. Whichever you prefer.
                 * 3) A set of reactions, linked to either a page destination or a function.* (See example pages)
                 * 
                 * Reactions can be emojis or custom emote IDs, and reaction destinations can be either the names
                 * of pages, () => { functions }, or special destination names. See below for a list of these.
                 */

                /* You can call pages whatever you like. The first in the array is always loaded first. */
                name: 'p2',
                content: new MessageEmbed({
                    title: 'Page 2',
                    description: 'This is some helpful info!',
                    fields: [
                        { name: "this is page 2", value: "p2" }
                    ]
                }),
                reactions: {
                    '⬅': 'p1',
                    '➡': 'p3'
                }
            },
            {
                /*
                 * A page object consists of three items:
                 * 1) A name. This is used as a unique destination name for reactions.
                 * 2) Some content. This is a rich embed. 
                 * You can use {object: formatting} or .functionFormatting() for embeds. Whichever you prefer.
                 * 3) A set of reactions, linked to either a page destination or a function.* (See example pages)
                 * 
                 * Reactions can be emojis or custom emote IDs, and reaction destinations can be either the names
                 * of pages, () => { functions }, or special destination names. See below for a list of these.
                 */

                /* You can call pages whatever you like. The first in the array is always loaded first. */
                name: 'p3',
                content: new MessageEmbed({
                    title: 'Page 3',
                    description: 'This is some helpful info!',
                    fields: [
                        { name: "this is page 3", value: "p3" }
                    ]
                }),
                reactions: {
                    '⬅': 'p2',
                    '❌': 'p3'
                }
            },
        ], 60000)

        /* Run Menu.start() when you're ready to send the menu in chat.
         * Once sent, the menu will automatically handle everything else.
         */ 
        helpMenu.start()
    }
})

client.login("Get your bot's oauth token at https://discord.com/developers/applications")
```

I'm making a page sort of thing and I want to allow everyone to be able to control the pages instead of just `message.author.id`. Is there a way to make that happen?

The thing is that I have tried removing `message.author.id` and replacing `message.author.id` with `null`, but it doesn't allow other users to react to messages. If I replace `message.author.id` with `null`, it just removes the message author's reactions.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your desired result? Also would be nice if you could add some of your code. Otherwise it will be hard to figure out where's the problem and what exactly you wanna do.

Comment: @Hoargarth my codes look something like this: https://pastebin.com/dvn84J8v
i would like for the people in my server to all be able to control the Menu instead of just message.author.id

Comment: You can edit your own question and add that new information to it. So everyone can see it at first glance and doesn't have to read through comments first.

Comment: updated, sorry im quite new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can only add a single user. If you check the [source code](https://github.com/jowsey/discord.js-menu/blob/master/index.js), you can see that the [`constructor`](https://github.com/jowsey/discord.js-menu/blob/master/index.js#L43)'s second argument (the user's ID) is used to get a single user like this: `client.users.cache.get(this.userID)`.

It also checks if the user who reacted is the passed down user (`message.author.id` in your case). If it's not, it removes the reaction:

```js
reactionCollector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
  if (user.id !== this.userID || !Object.keys(this.currentPage.reactions).includes(reactionName)) {
    return reaction.users.remove(user)
  }
  // ...
}
```

You can't just get rid of this argument, and you certainly can't replace it with a `guild.id` as the other answer suggested.

So the answer is, without [forking the project](https://github.com/jowsey/discord.js-menu) and making changes, you can't allow everyone to control the page.

Comment: is there another type of npm that i could use instead of forking the project (as im not that familiar with it)?

Answer (score 0):

Try `message.guild.id` instead of `message.author.id`.